# Intellij crashes frequently on running PsiSearchHelper

Tags: intellij-idea, crash, stack-overflow

I have a class file open - MyClass
Intellij is frequently crashing every 5-10 minutes and when I check the Intellij logs, it says:

```
2020-02-21 15:04:00,395 [ 142843]  ERROR - mpl.search.PsiSearchHelperImpl - Error during processing of: MyClassTest.java 

java.lang.StackOverflowError
              at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
              at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
              at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
              at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
              at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:559)
              at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:233)
              at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:303)
              at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:281)
              at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
              at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
              at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
              at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
              at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.write(QuietWriter.java:48)
              at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:317)
              at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
              at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
              at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
              at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
              ...
```

Any Idea on how to resolve this?

Is there anyway to disable the PsiSearch scanning? Is it advisable?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project and idea.log file containing the error.

Comment: @Andrey, done. - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the updates on the bug that was raised - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233718

The issue is fixed in a later build - 2020.1
Also the Helidon plugin needs to be disabled.